# Access jenkins parameters from parameterized build in shell script called from jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I choose to `This project is parameterized`, and I have two params: `query` and `index`. Then I choose to execute shell option:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "{$index}", "query": "{$query}"}}
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "myindex_output"
  }
}
'
```

I see that it doesn't read the params at all, and I get: `"type" : "index_not_found_exception",  "resource.id" : "{$index}"`

How should I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your issue might be on this line:

```
"index": "{$index}", "query": "{$query}"}}
```

i think you might want:

```
"index": "$index", "query": "$query"}}
```

you probably should add something like this to the top of the shell script to see what's going on:

```
echo "$query"
echo "$index"
```

the full answer is, assuming this declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  parameters {
    string(name: 'query', defaultValue: 'hot_query_value', description: 'query value')
    string(name: 'index', defaultValue: 'hot_index_value', description: 'index value')
  }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        withEnv(["query=${params.query}" ]) {
          sh('./shell_script')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "in shell script"
echo "query is: $query"

echo "anything query or index-related in env:"
env | egrep -i "query|index"
```

output in console is:

```
in shell script
query is: hot_query_value
anything query or index-related in env:
index=hot_index_value
ANOTHER_QUERY_ENV_VAR=hot_query_value
query=hot_query_value
```

even if you're not using a Jenkinsfile (why do you hate yourself so much? :D), the parameters will already be available as environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a environment variable. Use below syntax:

```
$ENV:index 
$ENV:query
```